# SQL left join automatic aliasing?

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I just realized that I'm going to have to start aliasing my database calls due to repeating column names in my join tables.  Is there a way to automatically tell SQL to alias all my column names so that they are returned with a prefix of the table name?  Otherwise it appears to be quite confusing when only some of them are aliased. Just trying to be consistent without writing tons of extra code.

```
$sql = "SELECT contracts.po_number, contracts.start_date, contracts.end_date, contracts.description, contracts.taa_required, contracts.account_overdue, jobs.id AS jobs_id, jobs.job_number, companies.id AS companies_id, companies.name AS companies_name
    FROM contracts
    LEFT JOIN jobs ON contracts.job_id = jobs.id
    LEFT JOIN companies ON contracts.company_id = companies.id
    WHERE contracts.id = '$id'
    ORDER BY contracts.end_date";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can make life a little easier by using table aliases:

```
SELECT c.po_number, c.start_date, c.end_date, c.description, 
    c.taa_required, c.account_overdue, j.id AS jobs_id, j.job_number, 
    cm.id AS companies_id, cm.name AS companies_name 
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON c.job_id = j.id 
LEFT JOIN companies cm ON c.company_id = cm.id 
WHERE c.id = '$id' 
ORDER BY c.end_date
```

Comment: If I alias my table names, do I still have to alias my column names to make them unique?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, you will still have to, just as in the above example.

Comment: @OrbMan, is it really necessary to alias if tablename(or table alias).fieldname syntax is used? If yes it must be php issue, pure SQL would not require it.

Comment: @Unreason: alising is not required in this case, it simply reduces typing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use alias tables in your sql statements so you have to write less, but to actually access the columns from php there's no way around aliasing all of them, if you want to access them by name.

you can also access columns with indexes from php, but that's a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to always alias table names. It makes it very hard to read later, if you skip alias.

Answer (score 0):

For info, theres a gotcha in MySQL 5.6 (possibly others!)

SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON PKI = FKI

works as expected.. but recently I mispelt 'LEFT' as 'LEFY' in a query and it also worked but with a standard join! so therefore

SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFY JOIN table2 ON PKI = FKI

also works just fine as does any substitute for the word LEFY, so beware a typo changing your query !!

Comment: Most SQL dbms won't allow that kind of error. First, they're likely to raise an error on join expressions like "pk1 = fk1" (ambiguous column reference, SQL state 42702). If you fix *that* so it reads "table1.pk1 = table2.fk1", you'll probably get a different error. The dbms will treat "lefy" as a alias for the table "table1", and you'll probably get an error about an invalid FROM clause, or something like that. This is certainly true for DB2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server. I'd be surprised if any other mainstream SQL dbms behaved differently. (Except MySQL. Nothing about MySQL surprises me.)